# How to restore a MySQL database "safely"

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

How should you go about restoring (and backing) up a MySQL database "safely"?  By "safely" I mean: the restore should create/overwrite a desired database, *but not risk altering anything outside that database*.

I have already read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-types.html.

I have external users.  They & I may want to exchange backups for restore.  We do *not* have a commercial MySQL Enterprise Backup, and are *not* looking for a third-party commercial offering.

In Microsoft SQL Server there are `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` commands.  `BACKUP` creates a file containing just the database you want; both its rows and all its schema/structure are included.  `RESTORE` accepts such a file, and creates or overwrites its structure.  The user can restore to a same-named database, or specify a different database name.  This kind of behaviour is just what I am looking for.

In MySQL I have come across 3 possibilities:

1. Most people seem to use `mysqldump` to create a "dump file", and `mysql` to read that back in.  The dump file contains a list of arbitrary MySQL statements, which are simply executed by `mysql`.  This is quite unacceptable: the file could contain *any* SQL statements.  (Limiting access rights of restoring user to try to ensure it cannot do anything "naughty" is not acceptable.)  There is also the issue that the user may have created the dump file with the "Include CREATE Schema" option (MySQL Workbench), which hard-codes the original database name for recreation.  This "dump" approach is totally unsuitable to me, and I find it surprising that anyone would use it in a production environment.
2. I have come across MySQL's `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE` statements.  At least they do not contain SQL code to execute.  However, they look like a lot of work, deal with a table at time not the whole database, and don't deal with the structure of the tables, you have to know that yourself for restoring.  There is a `mysqlimport` helper command-line utility, but I don't see anything for the export side, and I don't see it for restoring a complete database.
3. The last is to use what MySQL refers to as "Physical (Raw)" rather than "Logical" Backups.  This works on the database directories and files themselves.  It is the equivalent of SQL Server's `detach`/`attach` method for backing up/restoring.  But, as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-types.html, it has all sorts of caveats, e.g. "Backups are portable only to other machines that have identical or similar hardware characteristics." (I have no idea, e.g. some users are Windows versus Windows, I have no idea about their architecture) and "Backups can be performed while the MySQL server is not running. If the server is running, it is necessary to perform appropriate locking so that the server does not change database contents during the backup." (let alone restores).

So can anything satisfy (what I regard as) my modest requirements, as outlined above, for MySQL backup/restore?  Am I really the only person who finds the above 3 as the only, yet unacceptable, possible solutions?

Comment: Try a simple `phpMyAdmin` EXPORT and IMPORT

Comment: MySQL Workbench will allow you to restore a DB to another named DB

Comment: @RiggsFolly 1. I don't have PHP?  2. To the best of my knowledge, the Workbench will *not* restore to a database named by the user _if the dump includes the CREATE statement_ as I pointed out.  I have no control over the content of the dump file.  WB just executes statements from it (it simply invokes `mysql`).  It might contain a "delete all databases command".  That's why I asked my question about **safely**.  I know how to do it "riskily".  3. Letting my users loose in Workbench is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - `mysqldump` - I use this quite a bit, usually in environments where I am handling all the details myself. I do have one configuration where I use that to send copies of a development database - to be dumped/restored in its entirety - to other developers. It is probably the fastest solution, has some reasonable configuration options (e.g., to include/exclude specific tables) and generates very functional SQL code (e.g., each INSERT batch is small enough to avoid locking/speed issues). For a "replace entire database" or "replace key tables in a specific database" solution, it works very well. I am not too concerned about the "arbitrary SQL commands" problem - if that is an issue then you likely have other issues with users trying to "do their own thing".

2 - `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE` - The problem with these is that if you have any really big tables then the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement can cause problems because it is trying to load everything all at once. You also have to add code to create (if needed) or empty the tables before `LOAD DATA`.

3 - Physical (raw) file transfer. This *can* work but under limited circumstances. I had one situation with a multi-gigabyte database and decided to compress the raw files, move them to the new machine, uncompress and just tell MySQL "everything is already there". It mostly worked well. But I would not recommend it for any unattended/end-user process due to the MANY possible problems.

What *do* I recommend?

1 - `mysqldump` - live with its limitations and risks, set up a script to call mysqldump and compress the file (I am pretty sure there are options in mysqldump to do the compression automatically), include the date in the file name so that there is less confusion as the files are sent around, and make a simple script for users to load the file.

2 - Write your own program. I have done this a few times. This is more work initially but allows you to control every aspect of the process and transfer a file that only contains data without any actual SQL code. You can control the specific database, tables, etc. One catch is that if you make any changes to the table structure, indexes, etc. you will need to make sure that information is somehow transmitted to the receiving problem so that it can change the structures as needed - that is not a problem with `mysqldump` as it normally replaces the tables, creating the new structures, indexes, etc. This can be written in any language that can connect to MySQL - it does not have to be the same language as your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  One *big* problem with `mysqldump` is: user creates it with that "Include CREATE Schema" option, which hard-codes the database name.  Other user wants to import from tit, but he *may* have his own same-named database which *must not* be overwritten.  Executing that dump script *will* overwrite it.  Restoring user is nowhere near capable of spotting that in the dump file to restore from.  Disaster :(

Comment: If `mysqldump` has too many possible problems for you to accept then you need to write your own code. Not trivial, but quite doable in PHP, Python or any number of other languages.

Comment: mysqldump has options to exclude create command in the dump - `--no-create-db` and `--no-create-info` for not including create table (but this will obviously not create tables, if existing db doesn't contain such).

Comment: @JarekJóźwik  Thanks.  But out of my control one user creates the dump and *does* include the create command in the dump, sends it to another user who *believes* he will restore to a database name of his own choice, hits the restore button, and hey presto he has overwritten his own production database....  Where is the "safely"?

Comment: @JonBrave - You can't have it both ways. Either you control the details for your users or you don't. If you don't control the details, there will be problems, as you know. Either write real code, or use mysqldump but put it inside some basic scripts that set all the desired options (e.g., compression, database name, etc.). If your users can't be trusted to not mess with the scripts, then write some code. It would be nice if there was a generic-customizable-secure-cross-platform solution, but I haven't seen it yet. mysqldump comes close, but only if the users don't tamper with the details.

Comment: Thanks, and I do understand.  For "both ways", well, SQL Server provides BACKUP/RESTORE with none of these problems, I imagine Oracle does too, but everyone seems to be happy that MySQL does not, with the consequences.  Ah well....

Comment: @JarekJóźwik  Although no answer really "solves" my issue with MySQL backup/restore, I am marking yours as the solution because at least you address all of my possibilities, confirm that's all there is, and warn me off physical backup.    For which many thanks.

Comment: It wasn't me ;) You marked @manassehkatz answer as accepted. No problem, I hope we all shed some light on how mysql backups works. Backing up and restoring is always db admin job, and if you let your users do it themselves, you need to limit what they can do. In any way possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use third party tools (like innobackupex for example) then you're limited to use ... mysqldump, which is in the mysql package. 
I can't understand why it is not acceptable for you, why you don't like sql commands in those dumps. Best practice,when restoring a single db into the server, which already contains other databases, is to have a separated user, with rights only to write into the restored db. Then even if the user performing restore, would change the sql commands and tried to write to another db, they will not be able to.
When doing raw backup (physical copy of database files) you need to have all the instances down, mysql server not running. Similar hardware means you need to have the same directories as the source server (unless you would change my.cnf before starting the server, and putting all the files to right directories).
When coming into mysql, try to not compare it to sql server - it's totally different approach and philosophy. 
But if you would convinced yourself anyhow to use third party tool - I recommend innobackex from Percona, which is free btw.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have re-explained one problem with `mysqldump` in my comment to @manassehkatz.  Who would not regard "sql commands in dumps" as highly dangerous in production?  Users presses a button in my app in good faith to restore a backup, loses all his databases because of malicious injection, and then blames my app --- and I see his point.  For separate user rights who can "only to write into the restored db": in that case, how do you initialise the rights when the database to restore to does not yet exist on the restoring system??

Comment: As I can see it, you want to give users too much power - create their own databases, import dumps of other users etc - this is possible, but with heavily scripted app. This is also possible if you would give every users ... separate database server - not just the database. With such option - users can do whatever they want and will never interfere with other users. It is even possible to have multiple running instances on one physical server. You know - database admins are there for a reason ;)

Comment: To be clear, I provide the intended facilities through my own app.  I invoke `mysqldump` or `mysql` or whatever, just like Workbench does.  I am just looking for a way to exchange database from backup to restore so that "inadvertent" things don't happen.  Cannot see why MySQL can't offer a BACKUP/RESTORE without all this risky nonsense.  "It is even possible to have multiple running instances on one physical server" --- could be interesting, is that in the MySQL manuals?

Comment: I don't know, but there are guides on how to set up multiple instances on one server. Basic rule for that is that every instance uses different port to access and different pid files and logs. And obviously different directories for the data files.

Answer (score 1):

The export tool that complements `mysqlimport` is `mysqldump --tab`. This outputs CSV files like `SELECT...INTO OUTFILE`. It also outputs the table structure in much smaller .sql files. So there are two files for each table.

Once you recreate your tables from the .sql files, you can use `mysqlimport` to import all the data files. You can even use the `mysqlimport --use-threads` option to make it load multiple data files in parallel.

This way you have more control over which schema to load the data into, and it should run a lot faster than loading a large SQL dump.

Comment: Thank you for `-tab` argument to `mysqldump`.  However, it says "mysqldump creates a tbl_name.sql file that contains the CREATE TABLE statement that creates the table".  Those are just arbitrary SQL statements, so they could contain *anything*, and you just execute them (e.g. via `mysql`)?  Really??  In a production environment?  And if they contain anything "undesired"/"malicious" that's just tough luck?

Comment: @JonBrave, So read the file. Then digitally sign the files after exporting them if you want. Look, if your concern is that someone could tamper with your backup files, you have bigger security problems than MySQL can fix for you. Or any other third-party tool, for that matter.

Comment: Thanks, and I do understand.  SQL Server provides BACKUP/RESTORE with none of these problems, I imagine Oracle does too, but everyone seems to be happy that MySQL does not, with the consequences.  (I don't care if a backup is tampered with and restores bad data in its own database; I *do* care if it can affect other databases.  Apparently I am unusual in this differentiation.)  Ah well....

Comment: SQL Server also allows you to restore backup to another database, there are options to overwrite existing database and it will succeed if there are no connections to this db, but even if there are - one can terminate them and restore that db. As for every administration tasks, one must have appropriate privileges to do that - as one must have in MySQL db to do that, so I can't understand your confusion that mysql backups are dangerous, but SQL Server's are not. Every time you do something, you need to know what you're doing and need to know consequences of your actions.